# VBA code to select the first visible column in a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I couldn't find the exact answer to this query. I need code to access the first unhidden column in a range..the columns are hidden or unhidden dynamically and each time the code has to select the first column in the unhidden range..any thoughts?

My current attempt:

```
Private Sub Test1_Click() 
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Dim answer As String 
    'ActiveSheet.Unprotect "" 
    Dim rw As Range 
    For Each rw In Sheet1.Range("$c$30:$e$39") 
        If Sheet1.Range("b27").Text <> "" Or Sheet1.Range("b30:b39").Text <> "" Then
            rw.Formula = rw.Offset(0, -1).Value * Sheet1.Range("b27").Value + rw.Offset(0, -1).Value 
        Else 
            answer = MsgBox("Eh!!! There is no data to copy..Please fill the first column and try again", vbOKOnly, "Alert") 
            Exit Sub 
        End If 
        Next rw 
    'ActiveSheet.Protect "" 
End Sub
```

Comment: In order to get the best response here you will need to give an idea of what you tried and what the results were as opposed to "can you do my work for me"

Comment: Thanks..the following code works for all columns whether hidden or not

Comment: I am afraid my skill sets are very limited.. any help would be welcome

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is for the first unhidden column in the named range to act as a reference point for the formula to work for the rest of the range

Comment: Please [edit] that code into the question and delete those comments. Code in comments is impossible to read.  You likely need to look into `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(1)` to get the first visible column in a range.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. Because you have that statement, any errors your code is generating are simply being ignored. It is impossible to debug with that global statement. There are very specific cases where `OERN` is appropriate - this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Given an arbitrary range like:

Range("C3:H13")

and we want to **Select** the first un-hidden column in that range then:

```
Sub SelectFirstVisibleColumn()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("C3:H13")
    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    nFirstRow = r.Row
    nFirstColumn = r.Column

    For i = nFirstColumn To nLastColumn
        If Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

and if we wanted to limit the selection to the cells in that range rather than the entire column then:

```
Sub SelectFirstVisibleColumn()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("C3:H13")
    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    nFirstRow = r.Row
    nFirstColumn = r.Column

    For i = nFirstColumn To nLastColumn
        If Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
            Intersect(r, Cells(1, i).EntireColumn).Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]